# hide toolbar programmatically with coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

After extensive searching it seems that surprisingly no one is interested in the same behavior. Please point me to the appropriate place if I missed it.

The problem is the following:
I have a coordinator layout in the main activity xml. Inside of the coordinator layout there is a view pager. Inside two of the three fragments that I put inside the view pager there are recycle views that trigger the hiding of the toolbar in the coordinator layout. The third fragment does not have a recycle view though. The issue is that when the toolbar is shown the third fragment is drawn lower than it should, hiding part of the ui below the bottom edge of the screen. If the toolbar is hidden everything is shown normally.

So the question is - how can I hide the toolbar programmatically? e.g. when the user swipes to the third fragment in the view pager?

If you think there is a better approach - I would be also glad to hear that. Thanks!

Comment: Call hide() method on fragment 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer to your question :

I assume your `Toolbar` is included in a `AppBarLayout`.
To achieve it, you can add a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager`, and in the `onPageSelected()` callback call `setExpanded()` on your `AppBarLayout` :

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(position == 2) { //the position of your non-scrolling fragment
                    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true); //Hide the toolbar.
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
        });
```

### Alternate approach :

Another approach, won't say better, I'll let you judge depending on your content and user interactions, can be to keep having the same scrolling effect on your non-recycler fragment. 
You can easily implement that by wrapping your fragment content in a `NestedScrollView` (included in support-v4) with the corresponding `Behaviour` that will trigger the hiding of the toolbar in your `CoordinatorLayout` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<!-- Your non-recycler view fragment layout -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

A nice blog post about scrolling, tabs and `CoordinatorLayout` : https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

Comment: Thanks! `setExpanded` is exactly what I was looking for! Somehow I didn't think to browse the `AppBarLayout` documentation, looking at toolbar instead! Thanks!

Comment: And yes, I specifically did not want to wrap my third fragment into a scrolling view, because it is not intended to be scrolled. But thanks for the idea anyway